# Android: Google Map Android API v2 can't load map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I tried to add Google Map Android API v2 into my application, although I check every setting is ok but the map can't load into MapView.

Here is my design.

In the root project build.gradle file, I added:

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

In the application build.gradle file, I added:

```
...
dependencies {
...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And In the AndroidManifest.xml, I also added  tags:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY_KEY_HERE" />
```

And I implement an Activity which contain ViewPager, after that I loaded a fragment which contain MapView. I also checked all steps to initialize a MapView object inside the fragment.

```
private void initMapView(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
    mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

And call MapView's lifecycle functions in fragment's lifecycle functions step by step.

So Can you realize what happen to my code? I can't figure out the reason that make map not to load.

Comment: Are you sure your api key is ok ?

Comment: Where have you saved your `google-services.json`?

Comment: @Aznhar: Yes, Sure man.

Comment: @AlexT.:I saved in the app folder. I think these are not the reason

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Have you tried loading an example?

Comment: @AlexT.: Yes. It worked on example with my key